# Calabash how to use wildcards in Ruby methods?

Tags: ios, ruby, automated-tests, calabash, calabash-ios

Trying to figure out how to use the Predicate syntax in Ruby methods ...

Docs introduce the wildcard but forget to mention how to exactly use them in a query (or Ruby) so for a Calabash noob this is difficult. I tried this in Calabash iOS console:

```
query("* {text CONTAINS 'foo'}"
```

didn't work!

```
query("* marked:{text CONTAINS 'foo'}"
```

didn't work!

In Ruby it becomes more puzzling:

```
check_element_exists("* marked:# CONTAINS 'sometext'")
```

No go!

Can some Calabash genius enlighten me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The different samples you have posted all seems to be doing different things. I think it will be easier to help if you have a more concrete example of what you want to query for and what your view contains.

You have probably been by the [Xamarin page](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/calabash/calabash-query-syntax/)

Grabbing a piece from one of my own files I have used it like this in a similar check

```
res = element_exists "* {text LIKE '*foo*'}"
```

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks a lot! Had figured it out meanwhile and I'm using `not query("* {text LIKE '#{text}'}",).empty?`.